# Make a Test Class with Internal modifier visible to Unit Test Framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a unit test class like the following:

```
[TestClass]
internal class AttractionRepositoryUnitTest : 
             RepositoryBaseTest<AttractionRepository, Attraction, AttractionFakeRepository>
{
    //Code here
}
```

The tests inside those class are never found due to the `internal` modifier. To make it visible, one of the classes inside the `RepositoryBaseTest` has to become public, which is undesirable and to avoid that, I would need a refactorization that would take some time. Is it possible to make this test class visible to the unit tests without modifying it's visibility?

The Test class is the one that it is internal.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, @ErikE - from the source code sample you can see that the test class is the one that is internal

Comment: Solution A: change the unit test class from internal to public. Honestly, why is it undesirable? Solution B: use a unit test framework that do support internal classes, such as NUnit

Comment: @ricardo-alves you might need to change the title of the question, it's a bit misleading.... :-)

Comment: @RuiJarimba Just did it :P

Comment: @RuiJarimba Since the RepositoryBase is defined as RepositoryBaseTest<T, Y, Z> and T is internal, I'm obligated to put internal on this test. The only solution is to turn AttractionRepository to public, which is undesirable and I wanted to avoid. I could, however, refactor the RepositoryBaseTest<T, Y, Z> to "Hide" the T class, but that would take me a few hours and I would also like to avoida that,

Comment: ok, I think I understand now your issue. I was thinking that `AttractionRepositoryUnitTest` was the only internal class. Yep, you might need to use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`

Comment: @RuiJarimba Yes. I tried to use that but I'm not sure what is the name of the assembly of the test framework. I tried a few.

Comment: @RicardoAlves it would be really interesting to learn what `T` is and why it has to be internal. What possible unit test concern has to be internal to a unit test project? Your tests *are* in a different project from the code they’re testing, right?

Comment: Please show the code of `RepositoryBaseTest<T, Y, Z>`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what your looking for is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

InternalsVisibleToAttribite

Add this attribute to where you would like the internals to be visible to. Use multiple attributes where necessary for multiple assemblies.

If you can't add that attribute you will need to employ reflection to access that which is in question.

Comment: And to what Assembly should I make it visible to? I think I already tried every Microsoft Assembly.

Comment: @Jay from the source code sample you can see that the test class is the one that is internal

Comment: Updated answer, if you can't add the attribute to the source you'll have to use reflection

Comment: @Jay are you sure that will help?? His problem is that the unit test framework cannot find the tests because the **test class is marked as internal**. Please note that he is NOT trying to unit test an internal class in a different assembly

Comment: Yes, you would make the internals visible to the unit test assembly... why do you think that matters I don't know but this is the answer. You may need a 2nd attribute for the main entry point assembly as well so add 2 internals visible yo attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all type parameters of `RepositoryBaseTest` implement some interface you can just provide public implementations of these interfaces that wrap the internal implementations:

```
public AttractionRepositoryTestWrapper : IAttractionRepository
{
    private AttractionRepository _attractionRepositoryImpl;

    // forward all calls to _attractionRepositoryImpl
}
```

The same for other internals if needed.

Then `RepositoryBaseTest` can be made public, and thus `AttractionRepositoryUnitTest` as well.